# VS2013 WinFX.targets mangled, can't open new/old project files

Tags: .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013

I have a bit of a strange problem and no amount of googling has given me any answers or solutions. I'm not entirely sure if it belongs on Stack Overflow, but since it involves VS/NET Framework, I thought I'd give it a try.

Whenever I try to create a new project or open an existing project in Visual Studio 2013, I get the following error:
"Unable to read the project file ".vcxproj".
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(654,31): The project file could not be loaded. ';' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '='. Line 654, position 31."

I've discovered that the mentioned Microsoft.WinFx.targets file is damaged. Line 654 through 665 is filled with random binary data, beginning at column 31 as in the error message.

I have no clue what to do now. I can't reinstall .NET Framework 4.0 because it's already a part of Windows 8 and thus I can't run the standalone/web installers. I can't delete the file because it's protected by TrustedInstaller (which also leads me to the fact that I have no clue how or where to get a non-damaged copy of the file).

Just a bit of background info: I recently installed Windows 8, then upgraded to 8.1. I initially had Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate RC installed which worked at first. I hadn't used it in a week or two when I tried to load the Quake 3 source and first encountered the error. I thought it was because I was using an RC, so I uninstalled VS and installed VS13 Professional. Of course, this didn't solve my problem.

Any tips on how to proceed or insight into what may have happened?

The random data is the following:
;;Z<Ö<Û<æ<=F=Q=•=_>e>j>s>€>œ>«>°>¹>È>Ô>Ù>â>ñ>ö>ÿ>???+?0?9?H?M?V?i?n?w?Š??˜?«?°?¹?Ì?Ñ?Ú?í?ò?û?   € ¼   000/040=0P0U0^0q0v00’0—0 0³0¸0½0|2‚2“2™2½2Å23/373A3y3—3¸3¾3å3ð344Ð4à4 595C5g5†5Œ5—5ž5©5¾5ô586E6J6a6r6w6‰6¨6Ä6Û6÷677-7@7M7|7š7+8%9-9J9Z9};†;9>Q>]>b>€>°>(?ñ?  ü   ˆ001Ò1Ø1ã1ê12
222i2o2Œ2“2™2¶2É23:3D3O3“3í34,4@4v4Ú45D5H5L5P5T5C6^6Ü6¿7É7é7'8q8w8}8Š8“8™8H:Q:X:]:c:É:Ï:;f;y;„;Œ;”;œ;¤;¬;´;¼;Ä;Ì;Ô;Ü;ä;ì;ô;ü;<<<^>d>j>p>v>†>Œ>’>˜>ž>¤>µ>½>Ý>å>ú> ??? ?C?J?c?…?”?œ?ô?ø?   ¨   )000¬0½0Í0Ø0þ011#1/151=1C1S1Y1e1k1Ž1™1£1¨1¿1Ñ1Þ1é1ï1ø12222#2)23292?2Ð2Ø2ï2Ò34%4+464a4‰44”4Æ4â4ô45555%5*545@5F5L5V5\5b5æ5î56è6>•> >Ë>ð>? ?m?¬?¹?   ° d   ‹0Ø0â0°1ú12ë2:3D3'4E4W4¦4å4ò4Í56$6û6E7V7-8|8†8a9~9‘9£9â9ï9Á:;;æ;0>Ÿ>¬>‡?Ô?Þ?   À €   µ0ÿ01ç162@2F3Q3Õ3à344c4}4°4ó45Å5!616x6…6»6j7è7ý78g8È8Î8Þ8è899A9K9Æ9×9è9ù9M:’:ñ:;U;e<<ï<=y=•=æ=B>U>w>¶>?)?}?   Ð |   ›0·011M1Ç1ã172Œ2Ÿ2!3f3Å3Ù3-4K5g5á5ý5w6“6ç6C7V7ò7188¤8ô8: :Ž:ª:;4;…;Ú;í;
<ì>?p?w?Ø?è?ò?   à x   0%0K0U0Ô0å0ö01n1³12*2z23©3434¡4½45j5}5Ÿ5Þ5A6U6©6Ê7æ7`8|8ö89f9»9Î9ð9/:’:¦:ö:   <%<“<¯<=9=Š=ß=ò=>$>??y?º? ð @   Â0,1o1€1*2B2´2/373a3q3~36ñ6 708ÿ8ù9:(:3:·<=¼=Ù>d?y?     L   Ÿ0ó0K1Œ1›1©1Þ1{4U5ƒ5”6'7q9Å9:<<ˆ<ª<±<(=^=å=ì=>>°>·>8?Y?¾?Å?ç?î?  h   p0w0Ù0à01  1˜1©2À2$3Ê4ó4515Ï5,6C6ˆ6š6ã6767 8‚8ý8X9½91:8:Z:a:à:Ž;x<Å<6===_=f=Ø=î=>/>P>ý>˜?ç?     d   F0%1©1$3¨3¯3P4á4x5Ž5¯5Ï5ð56~6…6§6®6À78L899#:x:´:Ò:Ü:ã:é:);/;4;E;I<m<w<Â<÷< =^=ö=F>Ø>G?u? 0 d   (0/011Ø1^2l2{2‚22š2ü23$3+3 44È4Ï4À5Ó5ñ56,6=6y6†6˜6«6É6ñ677H7M79Ã9è9:Á:ç:;2;ï<=5= @ ”   171Y1|1Ž1³1ÿ1°2È2&3.373<3L3Q33464=4G4S4¥4Ï4a5§5°5¸6!7z7€7ˆ7ž7£7±7¹7É7ç7Ù809f9è9õ9M:o:º:©;0<C<`<}<™<µ<Ñ<â>>>^>}>œ>»>Û>û>?:?Y? P h   000L0i0T1~12,2³2Ý2Æ3â3ÿ3Î45A5Y5ø56(6E6a6}6™6ª6ó67J788V8@99¯:Ó:Ý:(;];†;Ê;b<²<6=¥=Ó=ˆ>>P?Ò? `\   h0{0™0¶0Ô0å0
1a1r1â132;2D2I2Y2^2•2 3>3E3O3[3»3å3t4º4Ã4Ð57Ø7-<Æ<Í<E=Q=>>>C>¾>’?   p D   0™12+2:2W2c2l2„2Š2ª3À3À657)9o9ý9C:Ë:j;§;Ø;ø;z<–<(=Ó=@>²>   € \   ª01B1J1Y1v1‚1‹1£1®1´1p2&3C5n5Í5.686V6‡6§6/7K7Ý799‘99:; ;•;¡;„< =e=û=h>³>M?•?    <   o1{1ð1ü1o2{2ó2ÿ2t3€3N4Z4Ï4Û4Ÿ56–618ð8°9;®;K<L=…?‘?   @   0P0v0~0$1=1Á122ä3“4Æ4X5–5©5²56a7!8|;ƒ;¸;Ë;<]=¦>ì>‘? ° $   Ô102Õ2 66<6O6‡6k7Ÿ7Ä7ò7±8         Å3ó344w4’44¸4È4å4\5       Ï3        n3   0    ‚3   @ (   D45575u8_9 =.?2?6?:?>?B?F?J?   P    0151?28Ï>?` @   å1é1í1ñ1õ1ù1ý12Y2'3?3c36†7#;c=g=k=o=s=w={==×=¥>´>Í>   p (   ç1(3¾6ì8ð8ô8ø8ü8 999ž9³:Ë:Ç;   € (   ï1z8ã8µ;¹;½;Á;Å;É;Í;Ñ;J<=4=X=    (   t0µ1B5€7„7ˆ7Œ77”7˜7œ7ô7m8‹8±8        E8Ý8û8!9€9“9®9û<ë=   ° ,   ’1´3¸3¼3À3Ä3È3Ì3Ð3X5ð5646ë67ô7C>   À     5L588
888888.8   Ð    Ñ9   à    õ<#>;>,? ð     ;5 <[7³9Ì:X;û=f>       F99¤9k;;     @     0[0b0÷1
25::¸:Õ:ó:;+;P;;œ;R<‘<ä<è<ÿ<
==L=P=˜=p>ˆ>> 0 P   J0j0ó0è1ð1ô1¢2ì2ð2÷2<3@3G3Œ33—3ä3è3g485ð6ø6ü67”8˜8Ÿ8D9H9ì;<&<1<4?j?¬? @ È   0 0'0 0§0(141^11º1¿1¨2¯2Ï2Ô283S3X3r3À3˜4n55Œ5·5Ä5â546<6T6X6™6Û6è677x9l:y:¢:¯:Ð:Ø:ô:ø:þ:;A;Q;À;È;Í;Ô;Ú;à;å;ë;ñ;ú; <
<<<G>R>ô>? ?'?.?5?B?K?i?¶?º?¾?Â?Æ?Ê?Î?Ò?   P œ   0  0<0e0Ñ0è011O1“1š1¥1¼1
2&2734`4n4u4Å4Ð4ß4õ455c5k5t5|5†5¡5µ5Ë5Þ56,6i6‚6©6ö6
7‰7©782888b89–9: ::;
;7;@;L;d;j;p;w; ?&?4?:?^?d?€?¯?µ?Ê?Ð?í?` ˆ   :0@0[0a0‚0ˆ0Ë0$1(151W1o1w11ˆ11á1ö152U2z2†2ò23s3•3ù3.4o4…4Õ4ë4;5Q5È5p7ð7[8n88Ÿ8²8Ä89$9ø;¨>?m??é?   p ”   0s0º0ü01n1„1à1ö1€2‡2ó23o3‘3494{4‘4í45_5u5ð5÷5c6…6ä67m7³7ô7
8Z8p8À8Ö8X9_9ì9(:¢:¯:È:æ:";J;è;ï;<9…> >Á>Ü>:?c?¨?´?»?î?ø? € ¸   Z0»0è0û0151P1]1j1r1†1”1¢1«155,575D5Y5_5g5o5ª5¼5Û5â5ð5!606D6Q6e6Ð6Ö6C7 7§7 88`8g8À8Í8Ø8ï8ú89 9&9.969y9Ž9—9±9Å9:::x::Ø:ß:@;Ã; <,<9E>˜>ó>X?e?v?‚?–?£?·?¿?Å?×?Ý?  ˆ   80D0 0b1i1å1ì1G2t2°2×23°3Ó3h4o4©4º4í4ó4H5€5™5æ5ü5636³6à6ç67E7Ð7Ù7à7ú738E8y8 8p9w9©9Ñ9ˆ::Å:ì:¸;Ñ;«<±<¼<=9=À=>!>+>A>„>¶>Þ>p?   ð   c2i2n2‘2—2œ2À2š3¤3±3Ù3ß3ü3444h4o4~4„4¨4®4¶4Ñ4×4Ý4î4ô4ú4h5v5¥5«5Å5<6G6^6ž6Ô6Þ6ä6ñ6 7.747B7G7O7U7c7h7p7v7„7‰7‘7—7¥7ª7 8'8n8s8­8²8¹8¾8Å8Ê8Ø899B9H9è9õ9û9+:1:S:Z:

Comment: A .targets file contains readable text.  Clearly yours doesn't, the file is corrupted.  Seeing disk drive corruption is never a good sign.  Not the kind of problem you can get help with around here.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't thought of that possibility. Maybe I'll put my drive through a diagnostic.